# Aliases don't work after restart terminal

Tags: command-line, alias

I have create few new aliases in `~/.bashrc` then run `source ~/.bashrc` and it worked. But after restart terminal it does not work. I looked back and found the advice: create `~/.bash_aliases` and in `~/.bashrc` append string:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

But the problem remains unsolved.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Type "alias" to see the list of all your assigned alias. Do you see your alias in the command output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly your terminal starts a `login shell`. In this case not `.bashrc` is read, but bash looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order.

try `man bash` and search for **INVOCATION** to read more.

It may be useful to source .bashrc in your .bash_login.