# What can cause my .profile file to not be loaded when a new terminal shell is initialized?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, user-profile, .profile

There are no errors in xsession and I don't have a .bash_login or .bash_profile file, so I'm 100% certain neither of those is loaded and thus cancels .profile loading.

When I rename the .profile to .bash_profile and open a new terminal window, it still doesn't load. Everything in the file works (aliases and PATH exports) when I load it manually via ". ~/.profile", but it won't load automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like this [was answered before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160789/aliases-dont-work-after-restart-terminal/160811). You have to be aware of the loading priorities of the files.

[EDIT]

You Have two options:

1. **(Not Recommended) Get your terminal to start as a login shell:**

   - open a terminal
   - Go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command
   - activate the "Run Command as a login shell" checkbox
     This way your .profile is read. But it also messes up the default loading behavior so I would recommend:
2. **Edit or create ~/.bashrc!**

Look [here](https://superuser.com/a/183980) for a good explanation about the difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile

Comment: Like I said, the other files do not exist. I only have one profile file, and that's .profile, and even renaming it to .bash_profile does not help. It never even tries to get loaded.

Comment: see my edit above, hope it helps

Comment: I think the proper way to load `~/.profile` is to do so in `~/.xsessionrc`. See this answer and my comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1281956.